# What should be in the Cargo.toml file at the root of the workspace so that Visual Studio Code supports all features?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Visual Studio Code says:

> A Cargo.toml file must be at the root of the workspace in order to
>   support all features

However I did not find what should be in Cargo.toml file *located in the workspace root*. Is it common for all project subdirectories?

I have read the [chapter Hello, Cargo!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) of the documentation, but it only speaks about the Cargo.toml files within the project directory.

By experimenting, I have found out that the file with only one line `[workspace]` makes the VS Code note go away, but now every time I set up a new project it nags me about the fact that this project is not mentioned in the members array within this "workspace" Cargo.toml

Visual Studio Code directory structure is as follows

```
workspace
  |
  ---> project1
  |
  ---> project2
```

the `cargo new project3` generates Cargo.toml within newly created project3 directory, but Visual Studio Code expects another Cargo.toml within the workspace directory itself.

Comment: [Chapter 1.3 — Hello, Cargo!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) of [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/).

Comment: @Shepmaster I understand that this is stupid question, but your link is not helpful, because it only describes Cargo.toml file for the project, not the file in the workspace directory. I have made it more explicit in the question,but it was contained in the original versions as well. Please, read the text of questions before downvoting them.

Comment: Do you actually have a [*Cargo* workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section)? I believe that message is referring to a *VS Code* workspace. This question doesn't seem to show any effort about what you've tried, what isn't working, etc.

Comment: Well there is not much to try, I have placed the file Cargo.toml to the workspace root, but still I do not understand what is it for.

Comment: Why do you believe that I've downvoted this question? It's that kind of assumption / accusation that makes people on Stack Overflow less likely to leave comments, leading to people downvoting without leaving comments.

Comment: If you did not, than I apology, it was merely a reaction to 4 downvotes, and one close vote, I may be overreacting.

Comment: If you follow the instructions in [Hello, Cargo!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html), you will run `cargo new`, which generates a Cargo.toml for you. Then you are done.

Comment: `cargo new` only generates Cargo.toml WITHIN the project, not within the workspace. It must be some VS Code thing.

Comment: Can you please eloberate why you opened a bounty? IMHO everything has been said.

Comment: @hellow I think I have commented on every answer and explained why it does not work for me. Especially I have been repeatedly directed to explanations for Cargo.toml file WITHIN THE PROJECT DIRECTORY, which is NOT what the question is about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in [chapter 14 of the book, section 3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). The Cargo.toml at the root of a Cargo workspace should explicitly contain its member projects in the `members` property. Note that this is exactly what the IDE was advising you to do.

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "project1",
    "project2",
]
```

Quoting:

> Next, in the add directory, we create the Cargo.toml file that will configure the entire workspace. This file won’t have a `[package]` section or the metadata we’ve seen in other Cargo.toml files. Instead, it will start with a `[workspace]` section that will allow us to add members to the workspace by specifying the path to our binary crate; in this case, that path is adder:
>
> Filename: Cargo.toml
>
> ```
> [workspace]
>
> members = [
>     "adder",
> ]
> ```
>
> Next, we’ll create the adder binary crate by running `cargo new` within the add directory:
>
> $ cargo new --bin adder
>        Created binary (application) `adder` project
>
> At this point, we can build the workspace by running `cargo build`. The files in your add directory should look like this:
>
> ```
> ├── Cargo.lock
> ├── Cargo.toml
> ├── adder
> │   ├── Cargo.toml
> │   └── src
> │       └── main.rs
> └── target
> ```

Another example of this in the wild is [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) ([Cargo.toml](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/Cargo.toml)).

The [Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section) provides additional details on the `members` field, including that path dependencies are included automatically.

> The root crate of a workspace, indicated by the presence of `[workspace]` in its manifest, is responsible for defining the entire workspace. All `path` dependencies residing in the workspace directory become members. You can add additional packages to the workspace by listing them in the `members` key. Note that members of the workspaces listed explicitly will also have their path dependencies included in the workspace. [...]

In this case, no path dependencies nor members were stated in the root Cargo project, leading to the sub-directories not being regarded as workspace members.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the piece of documentation I have been looking for. Do I understand it right, that this file should be edited manually everytime I want to include new project in the workspace?

Comment: @gorn That is correct, unless the new project is a path dependency of another member of the workspace. I have updated the answer with those details.

Comment: The whole system of workspaces and how they are conected to the Cargo.toml files is confusing for me, but you have helped to get me started, thanks.

Comment: @gorn Well, there is a chance that workspaces are not what you are looking for. They were specifically made for holding multiple crates that are part of the same project. If you just happen to keep multiple standalone Rust programs in the same folder, that does not usually merit a workspace.

Comment: That might be true. If VS Code was not nagging me about nonexisting Cargo.toml outside the individual crate directories, I would never started the question. It is more UI flaw of VSC than anything else ...

Comment: As far as I know, it's the Rust extension for Code that currently does not handle independent projects that were not opened in their root directory.

Comment: Maybe it is also cargo connected I get similar complaint when working with it in terminal.

Comment: You may wish to create a new, more accurate question on that matter.

Comment: Specifically `cargo new` says "warning: compiling this new crate may not work due to invalid workspace configuration", so maybe the workspace notion does not come from VCS at all ... I really do not know

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I was able to create a top-level Cargo.toml with the following content:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "./*/src/..",
]
```

With this, I can create new projects under the workspace without explicitly updating the top-level Cargo.html.

As a note, the more obvious globs like `"*"`, `"./*"` and `"*/"` do not work because the resulting matches must be directories with Cargo.toml files, and these globs match more than that (including "./target/", for example). The path I came up with results in the right subset (at least in the basic, typical case).